# SUM of column with Left Outer Join

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to get the Count of all records that have at least on person who is authorized on the record.  Basically, a Record can have more than one person associated with it.  I want to return the count of Total Records, a count of total Authorized Records where at least 1 person is authorized, and a count of total NotAuthorized records where no person associated with record is authorized.  It doesn't matter if one person is authorized per Record or if 3 people are authorized for that record, that should add 1 to the Authorized counter.

The current query is incrementing Auth and Non auth for each person added per record rather, than one per record.  If no people are assigned to the record that should also count towards Not Auth.

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT Record.RecordID) AS TotalRecords,
SUM(CASE WHEN People.PersonLevel = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Authorized,
SUM(CASE WHEN People.PersonLevel <> 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NotAuthorized
FROM Record
LEFT OUTER JOIN RecordPeople ON Record.RecordID = RecordPeople.RecordID
LEFT OUTER JOIN People ON RecordPeople.PersonID = People.PersonID
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that seems to be ugly (untested), but should be better.

As you must sum (the at least 1 authorized or not sum) by record, I don't think you can get it without a subquery...

```
SELECT
  COUNT(a.record) AS TotalRecords, 
  SUM(a.authorizedRecord), 
  SUM(a.nonAuthorizedRecord) FROM
    (SELECT
        r.RecordId AS record, 
        CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN p.PersonLevel = 1 THEN 1 ELSE  0 END) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  AS authorizedRecord,
        CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(p.PersonLevel, 0) <> 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0)>=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS nonAuthorizedRecord
     FROM Record r
     LEFT OUTER JOIN RecordPeople ON Record.RecordID = RecordPeople.RecordID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN People ON RecordPeople.PersonID = People.PersonID
     GROUP BY r.RecordId
     ) AS a
```

Comment: This only solves the adding NULL values to the not authorized count.  If I add 2 not authorized people to the same record, the overall count will increment by 2 rather than 1.

Comment: @Matt sorry, seems that I read much too fast. I'll read slower now !